# Controlling captions for subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

[image]

I want to move around the positions of subfigures as follows.

1. Move the Panel 3 figure below the Panel 2 figure;
2. Move the captions below the Panel 1 figure; and if possible
3. Align the subcaptions at the left of each subfigure.

How could I achieve these?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1}\newline\footnotesize#2}}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, tableposition=bottom, justification=justified}
\begin{document}

% test 
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=0.5\linewidth}
\subfloat[Panel 1]{
    \label{fig1}
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}}% 
\quad
\subfloat[Panel 2]{
    \label{fig2}
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[Panel 3]{
    \label{fig3}
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
\mycaption{PPC eigenvectors.}{I want to place Panel 3 figure below Panel 2 figure. 
Then write the captions next to Panel 3 (below Panel 1). If possible, I would also like to align the subfigure labels at the left of a image.}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, (almost) every time you end a line with `{` or `}` you are adding a space.  Specifically, you are adding two spaces before the image.

Second, you can put the `\caption` into a minipage to reduce the width.  Setting the width using `\captionsetup` doesn't help since `\caption` begins and ends with `\par`.

Third, I used a savebox to prevent resetting the subfigure counter.  One could also use `\setcounter{subfigure}{2}`., The savebox can also be used to help adjust the alignment (if desired).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1}\newline\footnotesize#2}}

\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, tableposition=bottom, justification=justified}
  
\begin{document}

% test 
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat[Panel 1\label{fig1}]{%
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}}% 
\hfil
\subfloat[Panel 2\label{fig2}]{%
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
\vskip\floatsep
\sbox0{%
\subfloat[Panel 3\label{fig3}]{% measuer width and height
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\columnwidth}%
\mycaption{PPC eigenvectors.}{I want to place Panel 3 figure below Panel 2 figure. 
Then write the captions next to Panel 3 (below Panel 1). If possible, I would also like to align the subfigure labels at the left of a image.}
\label{fig}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\usebox0
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations. If I may, could you add a few more explanations for the details of: "Setting the width using \captionsetup doesn't help since \caption begins and ends with \par."?

Comment: Using [width=0.5\linewidth] may make the caption look smaller, but it still extends across the available space.  LaTeX is packing the subfloats like words in a paragraph, so \par stops the paragraph and starts a new one.

Comment: Thank you. All clear!